# Timing difference on using timeit from interpreter and commandline

Tags: python, performance, timeit

From interpreter, I get:

```
>>> timeit.repeat("-".join( str(n) for n in range(10000) ) , repeat = 3, number=10000)
[1.2294530868530273, 1.2298660278320312, 1.2300069332122803] # this is seconds
```

From commandline, I get:

```
$ python -m timeit -n 10000 '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(10000))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 1.79 msec per loop # this is milli second
```

Why this difference in magnitude of timings in the two cases?

Comment: i remember python has problem for calculating float point data type.i suggest you use a module for do calculations.

Answer (score 8):

The two lines aren't measuring the same thing. In the first snippet, you're timing the calculation `0-1-2-...-9999`. while in the second snippet you're timing the string concatenation `"-".join(str(n) for n in range(10000))`.

In addition, `timeit` and `repeat` report the *total* time, while the CLI averages the time over the number of iterations. So the first code actually takes 12.29 ms "per loop".

Comment: I don't see it. Both times, the code that's executed is `"-".join( str(n) for n in range(10000))`, isn't it? It's executed a different number of times, but it's the same code? What am I overlooking?

Comment: @TimPietzcker In the first, `"-".join( str(n) for n in range(10000))` is evaluated and *its result* is passed to `timeit.repeat`. If there were additional quotes around said snippet, both would run the same code.

Comment: @delnam Can you elaborate please ? I don't get it !

Comment: Ohhh...now I see it. Wow. Thanks. This is why I love StackOverflow so much.

Comment: @delnam So then why is the first case taking so much time. After all I am pretty much computing nothing in `repeat` in the first case.

Comment: @abc: You're computing 9999 integer subtractions. That isn't nothing.

Comment: @TimPietzcker That makes me feel better.

Comment: Though to be honest, I'd expect CPython to constant fold these substractions. And my 3.3 interpreter does in fact turn `1-2-...-999` into the constant `-499500`. The same up to `9999` results in a stack overflow in the parser.

Comment: @delnan @TimPietzcker Wait the result is just a string see `join` so there must be no subtractions happening.

Comment: @abc We're talking about the *first* code, the one which is only substractions. The string concatenation also happens in the first case, but once, outside `timeit`.

Comment: @delnam Got it! Yes the concatenated string when passed to `repeat` behaves like a command string. Thanks.